# Problem accessing robots.txt from search script

Tags: perl, search

I have been using the Perlfect Search Script http://www.perlfect.com/freescripts/search/ for several years on my sites. For reasons unknown it stopped working properly a few months ago. When I run the indexing script I get the following error:

```
Loading http://emetnews.org/robots.txt...
Error: Couldn't get 'http://emetnews.org/robots.txt': response code 403
Not using any robots.txt.
Error: Couldn't get 'http://emetnews.org/': response code 403
```

The robots.txt file is easily accessible by Google and even visitors to the site. It has the permissions set to 644. I have not changed anything prior to the script no longer working. I can't get in contact with the script developer (they haven't updated the script or the site for a few years now). My Web host doesn't work with "outside" scripts.

Anyone have any idea what's wrong? I like the layout of the script. It looks very professional when in use (and its free).

---

Result of running `curl --user-agent libwww-perl/6.08 http://emetnews.org/robots.txt`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /robots.txt
on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

`curl http://emetnews.org/robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:

Sitemap: http://emetnews.org/sitemap.xml

# User-agent: Browsershots
# Disallow:

User-agent: NinjaBot
Allow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /_lee/
Disallow: /blosxom/flavours/
Disallow: /blosxom/plugins/
Disallow: /contact/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /feedback/
Disallow: /img/
Disallow: /includes/
# Disallow: /javascript/
Disallow: /lastrss/
# Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /mp3s/
Disallow: /print/
Disallow: /r/
Disallow: /sendPage/
# Disallow: /style/
Disallow: /talkback/
Disallow: /trip/
# block any URL that includes a ?
Disallow: /*?

# Disallowing the robot from Alexa from listing files in the Internet Archive
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /
```

---

Thanks for your help. I did have this in my .htaccess file:

```
# Blocks access from libwww-perl user-agents and URLS which include the command "=http:"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=http [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

I commented it out and I now get the text of the robots.txt file when I run

```
curl --user-agent libwww-perl/6.08 http://emetnews.org/robots.txt
```

Now, however, when I run the indexer, instead of it saying can't **get** the robots.txt file, it now says it **ignores** the file. ???

Comment: Try `curl --user-agent libwww-perl/6.08 http://emetnews.org/robots.txt`. What do you see? Try `curl http://emetnews.org/robots.txt`. What do you see?

Comment: I don't code in Perl so I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: your server rejects requests from `libwww-perl/` (default for `LWP::UserAgent`). You can change your User-Agent header (on client side). Or you can stop blocking such requests (on server side)

Comment: can you provide the full error message?

Comment: I can't post the error message as, again, I am limited to number of links due to reputation score.

Comment: try ask another question

Comment: ??? You mean a totally, unrelated one? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I mean a totally new question.

Comment: Posted @ http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219797/order-of-commands-in-htaccess-file